# How so I translate a MySQL statment to a numerical value?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am fetching a data from an external database, and feeding it to my dashing widget.

When the numerical data is returned to a widget, it looks like:

```
mysql::result:0x21A25
```

I need this data to be a decimal number. Here is the code for fetching data and feeding it to a widget:

```
require 'mysql2'

SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do |job|

  # Mysql connection

  db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "some ip", :username => "user", :password => "password", :port => 3306, :database => "database_name" )

  # Mysql query

  sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM out_sms WHERE type = 'STANDARD_SMS' "
  # Execute the query
  results = db.query(sql)


  # Update the Man Hours Saved E widget

  send_event('manHoursE', { current: results } )

end
```

Comment: It says that method fetch row is undefined for mysql::results:0x25AD3. Is it the right syntax?

Comment: Sorry, that was faulty or outdated information. The `results` object is an Enumerable. You can do something like `results.each {|r| ...}` to see what it contains.

Comment: It's recommended to use an alias for the `COUNT()` just to make it a bit easier to retrieve.  `SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM...`  Since this query can only return one row, and `results` is enumerable, you can just grap `results.first`, which should be a hash containing one element.

Comment: I am at the end of my wits here. Would you be so kind to produce some code that should work, I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: I fleshed out an explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mysql2::Client#query` method will return a `Mysql2::Result` object, which is a Ruby `Enumerable`. That means you can iterate it via lots of different means as you would with an array or hash (`results.each {}` for example), or [use `Enumerable` methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) like `.first` or `.last` on it.

Your query, having no `GROUP BY` can only return one row. so calling `.first` will give you that row.

```
# Use an alias for the count, total here
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM out_sms WHERE type = 'STANDARD_SMS' "
# Execute the query
results = db.query(sql)

# Then retrieve the row using a method like .first
your_row = results.first

# Look at the hash it contains:
puts your_row

# The value you want should be a hash key
puts your_row['total']
```

You can then use `your_row['total']` in your update method.

Of course, you can simplify it all and just use `results.first['total']`. Don't forget to wrap it in a proper `begin ... rescue ... end` to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql2 #query method returns on object of type 'Mysql2::Result'.

You can see the class here:

> results.class
>       => Mysql2::Result

You can get the array here:

> results.to_a
>       => [{"COUNT(*)"=>26797}]

And, if you just want the integer value:

> results.to_a[0]["COUNT(*)"]
>       => 26797

Renaming your count ('COUNT(*) as "sms_count"') will lead to a more readable result.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend looking into one of Ruby's ORMs, such as [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/), or [Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

They will make your life a lot simpler, by abstracting the queries using their own DSLs, allowing you to concentrate on the logic, and they'll return the contents of the fields as native objects in Ruby. No more issues like you're seeing.

These tools generate SQL equal to what you'd generate by hand; You have to work hard to make them do the wrong thing, and it's seldom you'll be able to improve on what they generate.

In addition, simply by changing your connection DSN you can switch to an entirely different database manager, and they'll sense the architectural difference, and generate optimized SQL for that new environment. Try doing that talking directly to MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle or SQLite drivers.

Here's an example of your what your code could be like using Sequel and SQLite:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite # memory database

DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Integer :number
  Float :price
end

items = DB[:items] # Create a dataset

# Populate the table
items.insert(:name => 'abc', :number => 1, :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'def', :number => 3, :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'ghi', :number => 7, :price => rand * 100)

# Print out the number of records
puts "Item count: #{ items.count }"

# Print out the values:
items.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Which returns this after running:

```
Item count: 3
{:id=>1, :name=>"abc", :number=>1, :price=>48.3673258126733}
{:id=>2, :name=>"def", :number=>3, :price=>41.87676958348104}
{:id=>3, :name=>"ghi", :number=>7, :price=>62.54605297923891}
```

In the loop extracting rows:

```
items.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Each time through the loop `i` is a hash, making it easy to extract individual fields. Running the code again:

```
>> item = items.first
{
        :id => 1,
      :name => "abc",
    :number => 1,
     :price => 70.81654554223003
}
>> item.class
Hash < Object
```

Notice that the integer and float values are what we'd expect. (The values for the 'price' field will vary because they're random.)

For Rails, you'll encounter Active Record as it's ORM. Using Active Record outside Rails is doable, but it's oriented towards that framework. We use Sequel extensively in my team for our DB interactions. My code-partner recently did a full conversion from a MySQL-based database to PostgreSQL in about an hour by changing the connection string, running the migrations we've set up, and kicking off a data reload. He was very happy with how easy it was, especially because he didn't have to write any SQL.

Sequel comes with a command-line version which is built upon IRB. You can interactively query databases, modify them, peek and poke at their contents. It's also a great way to see what will be generated:

```
Your database is stored in DB...
Welcome to SEQUEL. You are using ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]. Have fun ;)
>> require 'logger'
true
>> DB.loggers << Logger.new(STDOUT)
[
    [0] #<Logger:0x007f7fe41dd880 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007f7fe41dd858 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007f7fe41dd808 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x007f7fe41dd7e0 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x007f7fe41dd790>>>>
]
>> DB.create_table :items do
 >       primary_key :id
|      String :name
|      Integer :number
|      Float :price
|    end
I, [2013-10-06T09:51:55.752052 #6721]  INFO -- : CREATE TABLE items (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(255), number integer, price double precision)
nil
>> items = DB[:items]
#<Sequel::Mock::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM items">
>> items.insert(:name => 'abc', :number => 1, :price => rand * 100)
I, [2013-10-06T09:52:15.421974 #6721]  INFO -- : INSERT INTO items (name, number, price) VALUES ('abc', 1, 22.32640955200822)
nil
>> items.insert(:name => 'def', :number => 3, :price => rand * 100)
I, [2013-10-06T09:52:15.432649 #6721]  INFO -- : INSERT INTO items (name, number, price) VALUES ('def', 3, 43.182983199793824)
nil
>> items.insert(:name => 'ghi', :number => 7, :price => rand * 100)
I, [2013-10-06T09:52:15.441312 #6721]  INFO -- : INSERT INTO items (name, number, price) VALUES ('ghi', 7, 67.81054007143193)
nil
>> items.count
I, [2013-10-06T09:52:23.683121 #6721]  INFO -- : SELECT count(*) AS count FROM items LIMIT 1
0
```